# How to send Firebase cloud messaging after query device token from real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to send notification after success query device token from realtime database

my message

```
  let push_token = [];
  let message = {
  message: {
  token: push_token,
  notification: {
    title: 'new post',
    body: title,
  },
  data: {
    post_id: id,
   },
  },
 };
```

code for query token then send notification

```
admin
.database()
.ref('/devices_token')
.once('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    let val = data.val();

    push_token.push(val.fcmToken);
  });
})
.then(() => {
   admin.messaging
    .send(message)
    .then(response => {
      // Response is a message ID string.
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
 });
});
```

got an error on console

```
TypeError: admin.messaging.send is not a function at admin.database.ref.once.then
```

Comment: admin.messaging().send(message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the Admin SDK API documentation, [admin.messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging#callable) is actually a function that takes an optional App parameter and returns a Messaging object.  But your code isn't calling the method to get the object.  It's assuming that send is a property of the messaging function, but no such property exists.

You should use it like this instead:

```
admin.messaging().send(...)
```

Also refer to the [Firebase Admin documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) for more code samples that illustrate proper usage.